# Django Uploaded Image Won't Display - Other Answers Not Helping

Tags: python, django

I've searched other threads and tried to apply answers but I cannot get my image to display in a Django page.  Here's all of my relevant code:

Settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'main/media')
```

URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
    path('register', views.register, name='register'),
    path('logout', views.logout_request, name='logout'),
    path('login', views.login_request, name='login'),
    path('<single_slug>', views.single_slug, name='single_slug'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Model:

```
class TutorialCategory(models.Model):
    tutorial_category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category_summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category_slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tutorial_category
```

Views:

```
def homepage(request):
    return render(request=request,
                  template_name='main/categories.html',
                  context={'categories': TutorialCategory.objects.all})
```

HTML Display:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    {% for cat in categories %}
        <div class="col s12 m6 l4">
            <a href="{{cat.category_slug}}" style="color:#000">
                <div class="card hoverable">
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="card-title"><strong>{{cat.tutorial_category}}</strong></div>
                        <img src="{{ cat.category_image.image.url }}" width="200" alt="">
                        <p>{{cat.category_summary}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Any help is appreciated.  I'm new to Django and have been watching many videos to learn over the last several days.  Have many things working great but cannot get this image to display.  Thanks.

Comment: Please add to your question: 1) file full path, 2) file url your template generates (from final page html)  3) http status/response when trying to open this url manually

Comment: When you load the HTML page and inspect the code, what URL does your <img> tag point to?

Comment: @Sam, the img src tag is blank when the html renders.

Comment: When you check your media folder did you get the image in the same folder you wanted?

Comment: Have you found your image on server side? My guess is that your upload code does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `{{ cat.category_image.image.url }}` try `{{ cat.category_image.url }}` and see if the images are displayed. Also, make sure to have this in the form element `enctype="multipart/form-data`.

Comment: I changed the tag to {{cat.category_image.url }} and I get a value error that says "The 'category_image' attribute has no file associated with it."  It also says "'ImageFieldFile' object is not subscriptable".  When I view page source in the way I originally had the tag, the tag shows up empty on the html.  With this new way, I get a value error that doesn't render the page so I can't view source.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, wasn't expecting this to be the issue but looks like I figured out the problem.  Where I'm iterating over multiple tutorials and needing pictures for each category, I had only uploaded a picture for one of the 7 categories.  Once I gave them all pictures, they started showing up just fine.  I guess if I'm iterating over a model, each item must have all field values?  Can you assign a default ImageField value?

Comment: Yes you can assign default value or you could simply use if else statement, {% if cat.category_image.image %} then display image otherwise in else you can show default image